# How to remove obsolete users from ACLs and other unneeded data from an NTFS drive?

Tags: permissions, ntfs, mft

I have a hard-drive on which I have re-installed Windows many times with numerous users which have accessed numerous files. I’ve also plugged the drive into other Windows computers with other users.

Now the disk has lots of “unknown” users (users that do not exist in the current instance of the OS on this system) in the permission lists. Since I don’t have these user accounts anymore, I’m worried about these extraneous users in the NTFS access control lists hindering performance and making the MFT grow much larger than needed.

How can I clean all the unneeded users from the ACLs and if possible, refresh and remove all other cruft from the MFT?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about performance.  It's a B tree and it's unlikely to improve performance.

Comment: @surfasb but it may take some MFT space, although not significant